# Pattern for replacement "if else" statement

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have written following code:

```
var json = {};
var test = {
    run: function(json)
    {
        var choice = (function(){

            if (json.a != '' && json.b == '' && json.c == ''){ return 'a'} else
            if (json.a == '' && json.b != '' && json.c == ''){ return 'b'} else
            if (json.a == '' && json.b == '' && json.c != ''){ return 'c'} else
            if (json.a != '' && json.b != '' && json.c == ''){ return 'd'} else
            if (json.a != '' && json.b == '' && json.c != ''){ return 'e'} else
            if (json.a == '' && json.b != '' && json.c != ''){ return 'f'} else
                return 'g';
        })();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'a': console.log('a');
                break;

            case 'b': console.log('b');
                break;

            case 'c': console.log('c');
                break;

            case 'd': console.log('d');
                break;

            case 'e': console.log('e');
                break;

            case 'f': console.log('f');
                break;

            case 'g': console.log('no arguments');
        }
    }
};

json.a = 'xxx';
json.b = '';
json.c = 'yyy';

test.run(json);
```

this returns "e",  but json can be diffirent each time.

this structure of code is more clear to read, when there is lot of code lines for each "if" - statement.

Imagine :

```
if(statement){

//100 lines of code

}else
    if(statement){

    //100 lines of code
    }else ........
    //and so on.
```

I am wondering is there any kind of design pattern better than this solution ?
I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1):

Way easier. Loop through the `json` in a `for in` loop, and if there's any input, set that key as the `output`. If there's another input after that, return as "Bad arguments." If the test finishes, return the `output`.

```
var json = {};

var test = {

    run: function(json)
    {
        var output = null;
        for (var s in json) {
            if (json[s]) {
                if (output) {
                    return "Bad arguments.";
                } else {
                    output = s;   
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
} 

json.a='xxx';   
json.b='';
json.c='';

console.log(test.run(json));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r7Vyq/1/

Comment: unfortunately there can be all variants (1,2,3, 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 1 and 3,none).

Comment: Right now, your code only accepts one value being set. Is this your intention?

Comment: no it is just example i can add next "if statement" like if (json.a != '' && json.b != '' && json.c == ''){ return 'f'} else..... and than add "f" case in switch

Answer (score 0):

Well, how are you going to capture the user's input? If these properties are intended to be exclusive from one another, then you'd most likely use radio buttons as the way to capture input. You can only have one radio button selected at a time. Then there's no need to check all three properties. Just check each of them once, and whichever has value, return it.

```
var choice = (function(){
  if (json.a != '') { return 'a'; }
  if (json.b != '') { return 'b'; }
  if (json.c != '') { return 'c'; }
  return 'd';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous array and object methods you can use

For example

```
var res= [json.a,json.b,json.c,json.d].filter(function(str){
     return str.length;
});

var output= res.length==1 ? res[0] : "Bad args";
```

Seeing the JSON you are working with would help more

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uV2QD/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: "Bad Args" should also trigger if more than one of the json object's properties is not null. E.g. if json.a = 'xxx' and json.b = 'xxx', then return "Bad Args."

Comment: unfortunately there can be all variants (1,2,3, 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 1 and 3,none) json is simple {a:'',b:'',c:''.....}

Comment: @Kriss goes back to sample JSON and more explicit filtering rules. I pointed out a methodolgy for working with data... you need to provide a lot more specifics about filtering rules. Hard to create bulletproof methods without knowing all the criteria

Comment: He basically just wants a way to loop through the JSON data, and follow the following rules: 1) If one and only one property has a value, return the key to the property, and 2) If there are no properties set, or if there are 2 or more properties set, then return "bad arguments". His question is asking how to loop through without explicitly testing each property with it's own line of code.

Comment: i need specified bechavior depending on what user fill in json.If he fill "a" and "b" i need to run func1() if he fill "a","b" and "c" i need to run func2() if he fill "a" i need to run func3() and so on.

Comment: OK..made adjustment so only one answer can be provided

Comment: point of seeing full sample of json is can use other methods like `forEach` or `map` which cuts code I have down even more if only the elements you want to look at exist in object

Comment: there is only 3 json elements and 6 if else statements , but imagine how many it would be when json would have 20 elements ? too many - how to avoid such long if else statement ?

Comment: There are probably easier ways to organize this. I doubt you will be working with 30 different choices. Create a live html demo how you plan to use this. For example can set rules on checkboxes/radios

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
var json = {};

var test = {

run: function(json)
{

    var output='';
    var func =[];
    for (var s in json) {
        if (json[s]) {
            output +=s;
        }
    }


    func['a'] = function()
    {
        return console.log('a');
    }

    func['b'] = function()
    {
        return console.log('b');
    }

    func['c'] = function()
    {
        return console.log('c');
    }

    func['ab'] = function()
    {
        return console.log('ab')
    }

    func['ac'] = function()
    {
        return console.log('ac')
    }       

    func['bc'] = function()
    {
        return console.log('bc')
    }

    func[''] = function()
    {
        return console.log('bad arguments')
    }

    func[output]();


}
}

json.a='xxx';
json.b='';
json.c='yyy';

test.run(json);
```